# Flyway используя SQLite

Tags: java, spring, javafx, миграция, sqlite

Доброго времени суток.

Пишу desctop приложение(maven) под именем `videotagger`, в котором данные хранятся в `SQLite` базе данных.
Имеется *gui-javafx* контроллеры и `server`.

Имеется проблема с `flyway migration`:

`pom.xml`(videotagger)

```
<database.path>C:/ProjectsFromIntellijIdea/LuzhanovIgor/videotagger/videotagger/data/lindy.vcat</database.path>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

файлы миграции `.sql` находятся в папке

> server\src\main\resources\db\migration

в файле `pom.xml`(server)

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>alex</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.1</version>

                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
                            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
                            <version>3.8.11.2</version>
                        </dependency>

                    </dependencies>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>drop-create-database</id>
                            <phase>process-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>clean</goal>
                                <goal>migrate</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <driver>org.sqlite.JDBC</driver>
                                <url>jdbc:sqlite:${database.path}</url>
                                <table>schema_version</table>
                                <skip>false</skip>
                                <schemas>
                                    <schema>main</schema>
                                </schemas>
                                <locations>
                                    <location>db/migration</location>
                                </locations>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    </profiles>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
                <include>**/*.jpg</include>
                <include>**/*.sql</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

При сборке проекта *maven* кидает ошибку:

> Failed to execute goal org.flywaydb:flyway-maven-plugin:3.2.1:clean (drop-create-database) on project videotag-server: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to drop "main"."sqlite_sequence": [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (table sqlite_sequence may not be dropped) -> [Help 1]

Таблицу даже руками не могу удалить.
Помогите, пожалуйста, с решением данного вопроса

Comment: Проверьте наличие миграций в результирующем джарнике.

Comment: каким образом ?

Comment: Джарник - это обычный zip-архив, вскройте его любым архиватором

Comment: Проблема в том что джарчика нет т.к. maven не может собрать проект

Comment: А, он тогда никогда не соберется - у вас миграции ищутся внутри текущего в classpath, куда они попасть не могли. Используйте [префикс `filesystem:`](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/maven/migrate.html) для указания пути миграций на диске. Но вообще вы это зря, миграции должны применяться при запуске приложения.

Comment: Вы имеете введу в главном main классе прописать миграцию ?

Comment: <locations>        <location>filesystem:C:\ProjectsFromIntellijIdea\LuzhanovIgor\videotagger\videotagger\server\src\main\resources\db\migration</location>
</locations> и это кидает ошибку - Failed to execute goal org.flywaydb:flyway-maven-plugin:3.2.1:migrate (migrate-last-db-version) on project videotag: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Found non-empty schema "main" without metadata table! Use baseline() or set baselineOnMigrate to true to initialize the metadata table.